# How do I setup a ColdFusion datasource properly for a SQL Server database through Windows Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, coldfusion, datasource

At my workplace we are trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database on a different server. Our server is a ColdFusion server that runs the service through a proxy AD account. The owners of the database requested that we create another AD account and have given it access to their database through windows authentication. Upon trying to create the datasource for this connection in the ColdFusion admin page and entering the proxy account's information we receive this error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: xxxxxxx
>   java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'xxxxxxx'. The root cause
>   was that: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
>   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user
>   'xxxxxx'.

I recognize this is because the connection it was trying to make was probably through SQL Authentication, and that they probably do not have Mixed Authentication settings turned on (based on viewing previous answers).

So my question is, what other steps can we take to setup this connection properly? I'm assuming that on the database side they are not going to be interested in changing their authentication settings or anything, meaning we are stuck with windows authentication only. Do we have any other options?

Comment: Is your ColdFusion service running under the AD account that has SQL permissions? If so, then I think you just need to remove the username/password from the datasource and it will attempt to use the ColdFusion service user's credentials. If you cannot run ColdFusion under that account then I think you need to look at using the ODBC services that come bundled with ColdFusion.

Comment: Close, you need the username.  It's the password you leave blank.

Comment: Challenge the people who are telling you to create a new AD account for ColdFusion when it already has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/updated-datadirect-jdbc-drivers-version.html) is old, but the instructions for windows authentication still apply. To set a CF datasource to use windows authentication:

- Edit the DSN and select *Show Advanced Settings* > *Connection String*. Then enter `AuthenticationMethod=Type2` and save.
- Leave the `username` and `password` fields blank

**NB:** The ColdFusion service MUST running under the AD account with permissions to the SQL Server. It cannot be changed programmatically.

Comment: Looks like that is what we are going to need to do. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Since the CF Server must run under that specific windows account, you might also want to check what ramifications (if any) that has for any of your CF applications.

Comment: Yeah that's what we were hesitant about as well with this route, because we are not really sure.

Comment: Depends on your CF apps. It is unfortunate the default DSN type does not support changing the windows account on the fly. You could also look into @Miguel-F's suggestion of ODBC.  I have not used it in years, but ... odbc *might* provide more flexibility with credentials (not sure).  Also, this may sound strange, but take a look one of the lock down guides (by Pete Freitag). It should you a good idea of exactly how the CF user account is used on the server and what permissions it requires.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps to create a Data service with  Microsoft SQL Server that uses my AD Login Credentials -This was done in Windows 10 as the OS

Step 1 : After Downloading and Installing Coldfusion check under "services.msc" that you are able to view some of the Coldfusion services (Do look out for "Coldfusion ..... Application Server")

Step 2 : Right Click on the Service "Coldfusion ..... Application Server" and select "Properties" and then go to the "Log On " Tab . Here select the "This account " radio button and then enter your AD Credentials (Do check the AD user name using the browse button" so that you get it as confirmed

Step 3 : Go the folder where you installed Coldfusion Ex : C:\COldfusion23 .
Right Click on this "Coldfusion" folder and go to properties ->Security
Select the "Edit" button and then "Add" and add your AD profile the same you used in Step 2 and give it "Full Control"

Step 4 : Restart the service refer to Step 1

Step 5 : Launch your "Coldfusion Admin Console" ->Go to "Data & Services"

1. Give the Datasource name
2. Select Driver to be "Microsoft SQL Server"
3. Add the Databse Name ,Server and port and leave the username and password field
4. Go to Advance setting and in the connection string field add this "AuthenticationMethod = ntlm "

Click Submit this will add the Datasource

I found this in the article "http://web.archive.org/web/20151123073740/http://www.cfuser.com:80/windows-authentication-sql-server-and-coldfusion/" ,you can refer this too

-Thanks