# Creating datasource in CF2011 using SQL Server windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I just downloaded the free Coldfusion 2011 developer version and also SQL Server 2019 developer version both to my laptop. My Laptop is running windows 10. I tested my CF 2011 is working and also my MSSMS is working, created a test database, tables.

When launching MSSMS I think by default the Connect to Server Windows is set to Windows Authentication. All I need is to click the connect button and I'm connected to the SQL SERVER. Now that I need to create a datasource from my CF administrator I have an issue.

After I fill in the CF Datasource name, Server name, Database name and the default port 1433 error show up in red after I clicked the submit button:

*Connection verification failed for data source: TestDB
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: MYOWNPC:1433. Reason: Connection refused: connect*

Do I have to uninstall SQL server and re-install it as I wasn't sure if I have to provide a username and password in the begining of installation. Maybe that's the reason Microsoft by default chose Windows Authentication for me? What do I need in order for me to be able to create the datasource, thank you

Comment: Have you tried to add a user to the SQL Server, manually?

Comment: "Connection refused" != "Login failed." Have you checked in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager's Server Protocols that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled? Does the TCP/IP protocol have any IPv4 ports enabled and are they listening on port 1433? If you make any changes in here you'll need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect. You may also need to check Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to reconfigure/enable firewall rules that will allowing incoming connections to your SQL Server instance.

Comment: After you have connectivity sorted out... yes, you'll need to enable mixed authentication, which [you can do from SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode), and create an SQL Login with password for CF to use. Don't, under any circumstances, use the `sa` account and credentials in your applications.

Comment: Once you've verified the above (tcp/ip, firewall, etc...)  for Windows Authentication, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612373/how-do-i-setup-a-coldfusion-datasource-properly-for-a-sql-server-database-throug

Comment: Also worth a mention, although won't cause this error, do you actually mean CF2011? This is long unsupported now. Defo won't have support for SQL 2019

Comment: @haxtbh - Good spot. My brain read that as 2021!  user1557856 - You should install whatever version is being used in Prod (which hopefully is NOT CF11)

Comment: What have you filled in CF Datasource name, Server name, Database name? Have you tried using localhost as the server name?